# Jenkins - Get Build_id to format MMdd (usage of EnvInject ?)

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm doing some stuff to create correctly a release like 'X.X.build_number.build_id'. But I can't have correctly my build number like I want :

MMdd instead of YY-MM-DD_hh:mm:ss . With the ZenTimestamp plugin, it only change it on display, but when I try to pass to an other job, PROMOTED_ID have the same value than the timestamp.

So I tried to use a variable to format it, but it's not working ...

- I made a variable called ID
- I made a Windows Powershell build :

  $format = '{0:MMdd}' -f $env:BUILD_ID

  echo "`$env:ID='$format'" > releaseId
- I made an "Inject environment variables" to pass my new value.

I tried a lot of different solution, but nothing is working like I want... What do I miss ??

Comment: Which part is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Slav : My parameter wasn't set so I didn't have any value in it.

To solve it I used a groovy script, to recreate my parameters and add what I needed :

```
import hudson.model.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 

def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def npl = new ArrayList<StringParameterValue>()
def newParam = null
def oldParam = build.getAction(ParametersAction.class)
def dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd").format(new Date())

npl.add(new StringParameterValue("RELEASE_ID",dateFormat))
if (oldParam != null) {
        build.actions.remove(oldParam)
        newParam = oldParam.createUpdated(npl)
    } 
else {
        newParam = new ParametersAction(npl)
    }

build.actions.add(newParam)

return null
```